# Need help in iOS lib armv7 and 64 bit version

Tags: ios, 64-bit, core-plot, 32bit-64bit, armv7

I'm creating a project with Core-Plot lib.
I add the lib with [static way](http://www.raywenderlich.com/13269/how-to-draw-graphs-with-core-plot-part-1).
How can I run my app in 32 + 64 bit devices?

if I run `lipo libCorePlot-CocoaTouch.a -info`
console response:

> Architectures in the fat file: libCorePlot-CocoaTouch.a are: armv7 armv7s arm64

But this library works only with 32bit devices/simulator with 64bit simulator give me this error:

`ld: warning: ignoring file PATH/libCorePlot-CocoaTouch.a, missing required architecture i386 in file PATH/libCorePlot-CocoaTouch.a (3 slices)
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_CPTDecimalFromCGFloat", referenced from:
      -[HomeViewController configureSecondPlots] in HomeViewController.o
      -[HomeViewController configureSecondAxes] in HomeViewController.o
  "_CPTDecimalFromInteger", referenced from:
      -[HomeViewController configureSecondAxes] in HomeViewController.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CPTAxisLabel", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in HomeViewController.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CPTColor", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in HomeViewController.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CPTFill", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in HomeViewController.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CPTGraphHostingView", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in HomeViewController.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CPTMutableLineStyle", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in HomeViewController.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CPTMutableTextStyle", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in HomeViewController.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CPTPieChart", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in HomeViewController.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CPTPlotSymbol", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in HomeViewController.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CPTScatterPlot", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in HomeViewController.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CPTTextLayer", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in HomeViewController.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CPTXYGraph", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in HomeViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)`

How can I fix this problem?

Thank you

Comment: For working in simulator the universal binary should contain i386(32 bit) and x86_64( 64 bit) archs

Comment: I build a new lib, my console say:

`lipo libCorePlot-CocoaTouch64.a -info`


 `Architectures in the fat file: libCorePlot-CocoaTouch64.a are: i386 x86_64`, but it works only in 64bit simulator

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Combine both libraries and make a universal binary

```
lipo -create <simulator_lib>.a <device_lib>.a -output lib.a
```

Comment: it works! :) thank you. Now I have a lib of 19 mb, first it was 4,7mb. Is there a way to have a lightest one?

Answer (score 1):

Open the Core Plot iOS project (**CorePlot-CocoaTouch.xcodeproj**), update the architecture build settings to include 64-bit, and build the "Universal Library" target. This will create a folder called "Release-universal" in your build folder containing a universal library with all architectures (device and simulator) and copies of all of the header files.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I will try your solution as soon as I have time. thank you:)

Comment: When i do this i still get error like "Undefined symbols for architecture armv7s: "_vDSP_minvD", referenced from:" do you have an idea why?